# WPF download file from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I am working on a project where i need to download audio and video file from a SQL Server database. I am using WPF to do this. At this time, i have been able to display in a GridView all the files in my database that are allowed to be downloaded. This is what it looks like when the project is launched:

[image]

I have created a LINQ to SQL Classes in order to access my database data and display them as follow:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {

    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.TranscodeDBConnectionString);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Transcode";
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = from file in dc.Conversions
                    join codec in dc.Codecs on file.CodecID equals codec.CodecID
                    where file.Status.Equals("Pending")
                    select new
                    {
                        file.ConversionID,
                        file.FileName,
                        file.ContentType,
                        codec.Format
                    };
        ConversionGrid.ItemsSource = query;
    }
```

I need to download these file by clicking on the download button, this is what i have done:

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] fileData;
        string fileName = "";

        var query = from file in dc.Conversions
                    where file.ConversionID.Equals("14")
                    select file;

        fileName = query.First().FileName;

        fileData = (byte[])query.First().File.ToArray();

        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = fileName;
        dlg.DefaultExt = "";

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)

        {
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Here i specify to download the file with the ConversionID 14 but it returns me a blank file without any extension.

What i need is, on clicking the download, it will download the specific file with its extension!

Comment: are you sure your query is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the rest of your code is correct, to retrieve the FileName from the full path, do something like this:

```
string[] strPath = fileName.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\"));
fileName = strPath[strPath.Length - 1];
```

The code above will get you the FileName with the extension.

To retrieve the extension from it, you would just need to extract it in this way:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```